# Setting the width of a grid layout in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Im new to WPF and im annoyed I cant find this answer anywhere on the net.

I want to set the a gridlayout to have 3 columns. The first to be a quarter of the available width, the second to be half the available width and the third to be a quarter of the available width.

Is this possible and if so could someone provide me the Xaml?

Kind Regards

Ash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

The `*` postfix means a weighted scale, you could also use 1*, 2*, 1*

Comment: "25*, 50*, 25*" is the same as "*, 2*, *" as far as I know. Is there any specific reason you wrote the former, not the latter? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @triazo: No, there are many ways to write this. I would favor something that reflects the design motivations. I would use `2*, 1*` when something has to be 2 x otherColunn and `50*, 25*` when the design mentions percentages. And I tend not to use the default `* == 1*`